# Can't figure out why may object changes mid code

Tags: javascript, logic

I'm currently learning javascript and only a begginer (first month so the code is a lot amaturish). I'm trying to write some tic-tac-toe game purely on javascript and it should be something like this [Example](http://re-brand.us/projects/tic-tac-toe/index.html#) but I can't figure out why it's not working.

1. I have a class Game that handles almost all the logic. game gas two players each one of them also a class.
2. One game plays exactly as it should.
3. When I start another game and reload the board mouseover event behaves very strange. It should assign background-image with the current player symbol to li-element. And when player1 is active everythings as it should but when player2 is active the event function fires two times and the active player value changes. 
   I can't figure that out. First play is ideal. I will be gracious for any help!

(functions startgame and endgame just set the right html-markup)

```
    class Player {
    constructor(id, isTurn, css, img) {
        this.id = id;
        this.isTurn = isTurn;
        this.css = css;
        this.img = img;
    }

    checkStatus(boxes){
        let point=[]; let allpoint=0;
        for (let i=0; i< boxes.children.length; i++){
            let li = boxes.children[i];
            if (li.className.includes(this.css)) {
                point.push(i);
            }
            if (li.className!='box'){
                allpoint++;
            }
        }
        for (let i=0; i<winCombo.length; i++) {
            let st = winCombo[i].every(val => point.includes(val));
            if (st === true) {
                return this.id;
            }
        }
        if (allpoint == 9) {
            return 'tie';
        }
        return 'game';
    }
    }

    class Game {
    constructor(players) {
        this.players = players;
    }
    get player() {
        for (let i=0; i< this.players.length; i++) {
            if (this.players[i].isTurn === true)
                return this.players[i];
        }
    }
    get css() {
        return this.player.css;
    }
    shiftTurn() {
        for (let i=0; i< this.players.length; i++) {
            this.players[i].isTurn = !this.players[i].isTurn;
        }
    }

    set turn(id) {
        for (let i=0; i< this.players.length; i++) {
            if (this.players[i].id === id) {
                this.players[i].isTurn = true;
            }
            else {
                this.players[i].isTurn = false;
            }
        }
    }

    updateLi() {
        const playersLi = document.querySelectorAll('.players');
        for (let i=0; i<playersLi.length; i++) {
            playersLi[i].className='players';
        }
        const li = document.querySelector(`#${this.player.id}`);
        li.className='players active';
    }
    }


       document.querySelector('a').addEventListener('click', () => {

        startGame(); 
        const boxes = document.querySelector('.boxes');
        const game = new Game([new Player('player1', true, 'box-filled-1', 
        `url(../img/o.svg)`), new Player('player2', false, 'box-filled-2', 
        `url(../img/x.svg)`)]); 

        game.updateLi();     


        boxes.addEventListener('mouseover', (e) => {
            if (e.target.className=='box') {
           /*  if (document.querySelector('a').innerText=='New 
                  game'&&game.player.id=='player2'){
                    console.log(game.player.img);
                } */
                    e.target.style.backgroundImage=game.player.img;
            }
        })

        boxes.addEventListener('mouseout', (e) => {
            if (e.target.className=='box') {
               // if (document.querySelector('a').innerText!='New game'){
                   e.target.style.backgroundImage='none';
               // }
            }
        }) 

        boxes.addEventListener('click', (e) => {
            if (e.target.className=='box') {
                e.target.removeAttribute('style');
                e.target.className='box '+game.css;  
                let status = game.player.checkStatus(e.target.parentNode);

                if (status != 'game') {
                    if (document.querySelector('a').innerText=='New game'){
                        console.log(status);
                    }
                    endGame(status);
                    game.turn='player1';
                }
                else {
                    game.shiftTurn();
                    game.updateLi();
                }

              //  console.log(status);
            }
        })
         })
         });
```

Comment: Can you post the HTML too, perhaps in a live snippet, so that your problem can be reproduced? (Need a [MCVE] to work with)

Comment: Maybe you're registering the eventListener twice when starting a new game, try to start a third time and see if the behavior extends to 3 actions on `mouseover`. If that's the case, remove the `addEventListener` from the start game or just check if there is an event before adding another one.